# I have this code but i want to make it so it gives how many members are they on the server that the bot joined, it doesn't give me a error

Tags: discord, discord.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import requests
import time
import random 


@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    channel = client.get_channel(899768588011966478)
    invite = await guild.system_channel.create_invite()

    e = discord.Embed(color=0xd41818,title="I joined a server")
    e.add_field(name="Server Name", value=guild.name, inline=False)
    e.add_field(name="Invite", value=invite, inline=False)
    e.add_field(name="Members", value=guild.members, inline=False)
    await channel.send(embed=e)



client.run(token)
```

On the embed

[<Member id=849182756936830986 name='Account,' discriminator='1057' bot=False nick=None guild=>, <Member id=899767778590986343 name='test bot' discriminator='7215' bot=True nick=None guild=>]

Comment: You are trying to get `guild.members` but you have to get the `len` of that. Otherwise the code will not work how you want it to.

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

In the third field, the value is

```py
guild.member_count
```

So the event will be

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    channel = client.get_channel(899768588011966478)
    invite = await guild.system_channel.create_invite()

    e = discord.Embed(color=0xd41818,title="I joined a server")
    e.add_field(name="Server Name", value=guild.name, inline=False)
    e.add_field(name="Invite", value=invite, inline=False)
    e.add_field(name="Members", value=guild.member_count, inline=False)
    await channel.send(embed=e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use guild.member_count instead of the guild.members